# modify array element through pointer to a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to build a program that modifies the element of an array through a pointer to a pointer. I loaded it into the debugger and I see that the value of my pointer changes, but for some reason that doesn't affect the element in the array. Is my pointer syntax wrong? Am I reassigning my pointer somewhere else?

```css
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 6

/*
 * 
 */


void change (char **x);

int main() {
    
    char arra[] = "Back";
    char *c = arra;
    
    change(&c);
    
    int i; 
    printf("%c", arra[0]);
    }
    
   

void change (char **x) {
    
    *x = "H";
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
*x = "H";
```

should be

```
**x = 'H';
```

You are trying to modify the first character and character has to be within single quotes.

There is no need of pointer to pointer here. You can just pass the array which decays to a pointer when passed in the function parameterks as shown by **@haccks**

Comment: Does `and` from your statement mean `that's why`?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use *pointer to pointer* in this case. Just use pointer to `char`.

```
void change (char *x);
```

and call it as

```
change(c);
```

with the function body

```
 void change (char *x) { 
    *x = 'H';   
}
```